# Adafruit 1.5" & 2.1" Monochrome 128x64 OLED Display Module not working SPI

Tags: arduino, screen, spi, adafruit

I am following this tutorial.

https://learn.adafruit.com/1-5-and-2-1-monochrome-128x64-oled-display-module/wiring-and-test

For some reason i'm not getting any life from the oled screen. I have checked the voltages on all the pins and they are as they should be (around 3v).Resisters are correctly positioned for SPI.

[image: Back of screen]
[image: Wiring]

using this example if code

```
    /*********************************************************************
This is a library for our Monochrome OLEDs based on SSD1305 drivers

  Pick one up today in the adafruit shop!
  ------> https://www.adafruit.com/products/2675

These displays use SPI or I2C to communicate, 3-5 pins are required to  
interface

Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
products from Adafruit!

Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada  for Adafruit Industries.  
BSD license, check license.txt for more information
All text above, and the splash screen below must be included in any redistribution
*********************************************************************/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1305.h>

// Used for software SPI
#define OLED_CLK 13
#define OLED_MOSI 11

// Used for software or hardware SPI
#define OLED_CS 10
#define OLED_DC 8

// Used for I2C or SPI
#define OLED_RESET 9

// software SPI
Adafruit_SSD1305 display(OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
// hardware SPI
//Adafruit_SSD1305 display(OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);

// I2C
//Adafruit_SSD1305 display(OLED_RESET);

#define NUMFLAKES 10
#define XPOS 0
#define YPOS 1
#define DELTAY 2


#define LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT 16 
#define LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH  16 
static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo16_glcd_bmp[] =
{ B00000000, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000011, B11100000,
  B11110011, B11100000,
  B11111110, B11111000,
  B01111110, B11111111,
  B00110011, B10011111,
  B00011111, B11111100,
  B00001101, B01110000,
  B00011011, B10100000,
  B00111111, B11100000,
  B00111111, B11110000,
  B01111100, B11110000,
  B01110000, B01110000,
  B00000000, B00110000 };

void fill(unsigned char dat1,unsigned char dat2)
{
  unsigned char x,y;
  for(y=0;y<8;y++)
  {
    display.command(0xb0+y);
    display.command(0x00);
    display.command(0x10);
    for(x=0;x<132;x++)
    {
      display.data(dat1);
      display.data(dat2);
    }
  }
}


void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SSD1305 OLED test");

  // by default, we'll generate the high voltage from the 3.3v line internally! (neat!)
  display.begin();
  // init done

  display.display(); // show splashscreen
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();   // clears the screen and buffer

  // draw a single pixel
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw many lines
  testdrawline();
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw rectangles
  testdrawrect();
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw multiple rectangles
  testfillrect();
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw mulitple circles
  testdrawcircle();
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw a white circle, 10 pixel radius
  display.fillCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, 10, WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawroundrect();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfillroundrect();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawtriangle();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfilltriangle();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw the first ~12 characters in the font
  testdrawchar();
  display.display();
  delay(1000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  for (uint8_t rot=0; rot < 4; rot++) {
    display.setRotation(rot);
    display.clearDisplay();
    // text display tests
    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    display.println("Hello, world!");
    display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE); // 'inverted' text
    display.println(3.141592);
    display.setTextSize(2);
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.print("0x"); display.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
    display.display();
    delay(1000);
  }

  display.setRotation(0);

  // miniature bitmap display
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.drawBitmap(30, 16,  logo16_glcd_bmp, 16, 16, 1);
  display.display();

  // invert the display
  display.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(1000); 
  display.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(1000); 

  // draw a bitmap icon and 'animate' movement
  testdrawbitmap(logo16_glcd_bmp, LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT, LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH);
}


void loop() {
}


void testdrawbitmap(const uint8_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h) {
  uint8_t icons[NUMFLAKES][3];
  srandom(666);     // whatever seed

  // initialize
  for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random() % display.width();
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random() % 5 + 1;

    Serial.print("x: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][XPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" y: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][YPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" dy: ");
    Serial.println(icons[f][DELTAY], DEC);
  }

  while (1) {
    // draw each icon
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS], logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, WHITE);
    }
    display.display();
    delay(200);

    // then erase it + move it
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS],  logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, BLACK);
      // move it
      icons[f][YPOS] += icons[f][DELTAY];
      // if its gone, reinit
      if (icons[f][YPOS] > display.height()) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random() % display.width();
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random() % 5 + 1;
      }
    }
   }
}


void testdrawchar(void) {
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextWrap(false);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);

  for (uint8_t i=0; i < 168; i++) {
    if (i == '\n') continue;
    display.write(i);
    if ((i > 0) && (i % 21 == 0))
      display.println();
  }    
  display.display();
}

void testdrawcircle(void) {
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=2) {
    display.drawCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = 1;
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=3) {
    // alternate colors
    display.fillRect(i, i, display.width()-i*2, display.height()-i*2, color%2);
    display.display();
    color++;
  }
}

void testdrawtriangle(void) {
  for (uint16_t i=0; i<min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i+=5) {
    display.drawTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfilltriangle(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (int16_t i=min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i>0; i-=5) {
    display.fillTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawroundrect(void) {
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height()/3-2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillroundrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height()/3-2; i+=2) {
    display.fillRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, color);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawrect(void) {
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawline() {  
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int8_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int8_t i=display.width()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int8_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE); 
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

We have double and triple checked the wiring. Does anyone know of any checks besides measuring voltage on each pin I can carry out to establish whether this is simply a faulty screen?

Comment: Have you also done this part: "You will also want to power the HC4050 level shifter by connecting pin #1 to 3V (the red wire) and pin #8 to ground (the black wire)" ?

Comment: Yep, HC4050 has power and ground